# Как заставить блок не растягиваться зазря?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с плашкой поверх него, типа такого:

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<div class="plashka">
Здесь нужно что-то длинное
</div>
</div>
```

Плашка растягивается на всю длину родительского блока, а я хочу вот так — чтобы у плашки не было вообще никакого внутреннего отступа ни слева, ни справа:

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<div class="plashka">
Здесь нужно что-то<br/>длинное
</div>
</div>
```

Возможно ли это без явно прописанного `<br/>` и без каких-либо ограничений на ширину? Чтобы всё само подстраивалось под текст.

UPD: ещё пример для наглядности:

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
Как не надо:
<div class="plashka">
а б в г д е ё еёжзийклмно
</div>
Как надо:
<div class="plashka">
а б в г д е ё<br/>еёжзийклмно
</div>
<hr/>
Как не надо:
<div class="plashka">
а б в гдеё ж з и к л мнопрстуфх
</div>
Как надо:
<div class="plashka">
а б в гдеё ж з и к л<br/>мнопрстуфх
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит подстраивалось под текст? Под одно слово, 2, 3?

Comment: `padding` родителю то нельзя добавить?

Comment: @wcobalt это значит чтобы текст целиком вписывался в блок без лишних полей как в первом примере, количество слов может быть любым от нуля до сколько в оперативу влезет)

Comment: @teran по сути это добавление ограничения длины потомку, поля уменьшатся, но никуда не денутся

Comment: Добавил ещё пример для наглядности

Answer (score 2):

Из-за особенностей блочного контекста форматирования (а внутри `inline-block` именно он) у вас не получится это сделать по-простому через CSS.

Решение на JS такое:

```js
document.querySelector('.plashka').style.width = document.querySelector('.plashka__inner').getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
```

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="plashka">
    <span class="plashka__inner">Здесь нужно что-то длинное</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет такого? Не самое элегантное решение, но без переноса оно будет доводить до максимума, поэтому таких отступов нет. Чтобы их добавить я предлагаю отступать сразу от `foo` блока слева и справа.

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<div class="plashka">
Ваш длинный текст
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отступы внутри плашки хоть и меньше на 20 пикселей, но всё ещё присутствуют, то есть по-прежнему растягивается зазря. Плюс, например, «Длииинный теееекст» вполне влезает в одну строчку, в то время как с таким маргином он занимает две, что меня тоже не очень устраивает

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса:

```css
.foo {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eef;
  border: 1px solid #77f;
  text-align: center;
}

.plashka {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaf;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<div class="plashka">
Здесь нужно что-то длинное
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поля у внутреннего блока всё ещё есть, и на тексте `а б в г д е ё еёжзийклмно` они целых 27 пикселей