# Перенос текста занимает полную длину блока

Tags: css

Допустим, есть некий блок и его длина составляет 165 пикселей. Я помещаю в этот блок некий текст, который заведомо не поместится в этом блоке и слово будет перенесено в новый ряд. Но проблема в том, что хоть текст и будет перенесён, но он всё равно займет всю длину блока(см. снипет). Как видно, после переноса образовалось много свободного пространства. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы блок занимал только тот объём пространства, который занимает вложенный в него текст? Простыми словами, нужно освободить всё то пространство в левой части блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block {
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
    max-width: 165px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Санкт-Петербург</div>
```

Comment: не очень понял вопрос. Нужно тупа чтобы блок занимал ширину вложенного в него текста?

Comment: max-width просто сократить может?

Comment: [Что-то похожее я уже спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670316)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
    max-width: min-content;
    max-width: -moz-min-content;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Санкт-Петербург</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, для фразы типа «а б в г д» получится результат возможно отличный от того, что ожидает автор