# бордер по ширине текста

Tags: html, css

Есть блок в котором есть текст, если слова перенеслись на новую строку, блок стал меньше, нужно чтоб снизу был бордер по ширине текста [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

inline-block не подходит так как если слова перенеслись то блок будит считаться по всей ширине и бордер растянется. Так же пробовал внутри вставлять `<span>` и ему делать бордер но тогда каждая строка будит с бордером. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу сообразить как сделать чтобы бордер был как на 1 картинке?

Comment: без js никак, а с js респонзив делать тоже как-то не сок

Comment: Я так и понял, что дизайнера нужно на кол посадить))

Comment: Связанный вопрос про вариант с inline-block: [Как заставить блок не растягиваться зазря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670316)

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось можно, для inline элементов псевдоселектор принимает ширину последнего.

```css
h2 {
  font: 28px/30px Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 20px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

h2:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

div { padding: 20px; }

.test1 {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.test2 {
  max-width: 60%;
}

.test3 {
  max-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <h2>Расширенная гарантия Tyres</h2>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <h2>Расширенная Tyres гарантия</h2>
</div>
<div class="test3">
  <h2>Tyres гарантия Расширенная</h2>
</div>
```

Не проверял во всех браузерах, но в хроме все отлично

Comment: почти то, но нужно по самой длинной строке, пробовал так))

Comment: значит я не так понял, думал надо красиво) так по самой длинной строке то вообще не проблема. inline-block и бордер

Comment: а через inline-block тоже не то, если текст внутри перенесся, то блок как бы считается на 100%, уже все варианты перепробовал, по ходу ни как)))

Comment: @Karalahti тогда block с float: right

Comment: так все равно если текст перенесся то он как 100% считается, то же что и с инлайн блоком, вся трабла из-за текста, в общем я уже понял что решения нету увы, сделал просто через before и дал ширину в процентах, а дизайнеру дал по шапке ))))

Comment: элементы которые с позиционированы как position:absolute; будут искать родителя с position:relative; и будут вести себя относительно этого родителя, и тут inline или не inline не играет роли. А делать адаптивку используя размер элемента фиксироваными величинами- это глупо и не профессионально. Решение есть всегда.

Comment: @SergeyB это вы вообще к чему?

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev это я к последнему коментарию  пользователя Karalahti

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```css
.asd {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-bottom-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="asd">Расширенная гарантия Tyres</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
section{
width:50px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.text{
position:relative;
padding-bottom:2px;
}
.text:before{
content:'';
position:absolute;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="text">
Hello world
</div>
</section>
```

При разных размерах ширины блока section линия всегда будет одна.

если нужно тупо для одного слова подчеркивание, то тогда так:

```css
section {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="text">
    Hello <span>world</span> hello <span>world</span> hello
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: это не совсем то что нужно, так как блок не статичный, а адаптивный, бордер должен подстраиваться под текст, если текст перенесся на следующую строку то блок стал меньше, грубо говоря не блок а span

Comment: блок section для примера был вставлен.Если section сделать адаптивным - бордер будет все равно на всю его ширину и будет той длинны какой длинны текст.

Comment: Вы хоть когда пример пишите вникните в то, что требуется. Загаловок может состоять из разного количества слов, когда слов много и они не влазят то пишутся с новой строки и как бы визуально блок становится меньше, а по факту он растягивается на всю ширину. И бордер нужно сделать относительно ширины текста. В вашем коде вы взяли и разбили текст на 2 разных слова. Как вы себе это представляете реализовать если конечного текста вы не знаете.

Answer (score -4):

Зачем вам бордер, если для подчеркивания текста есть свойство text-decoration

```css
p {
  display: block;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Расширенная <span>гарантия Tyres</span>
</p>
```

Comment: А если ширины для двух слов будет недостаточно?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров в таком случае можно не указывать фиксированную ширину, а переносы в нужных местах делать через <br>?

Comment: Стиль у text-decoration совершенно не тот

Comment: @andreymal уууу как меня заминусовали :D. Нужно подумать 7 раз прежде чем дать ответ, и быть повнимательней не торопясь с ответом. А так, да, стиль другой, и отступ есть. Тут text-decoration ни к чему